# Docker Compose - Starting already created containers

Tags: windows, docker, selenium-grid

I am new to Docker and I am trying to run Selenium Grid tests on Docker. For this purpose, I created a docker compose file and executed below command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up
```

Everything worked fine but after a few hours I restarted host machine and executed above command again. This time I get below error

```
ERROR: for selenium-hub  Cannot create container for service selenium-hub: Conflict. The container name "/selenium-hub" is already in use by container "some-hash". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

I tried `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml run selenium-hub` but this command does not start selenium nodes. So my questions are -

- Do I need to remove the container everytime before I run the docker compose 
  again?
- Is there any way I can use docker-compose like file, so that
  everytime I restart docker, I can just run the file to start all containers together?

Below the Docker-Compose I used

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-20200525
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-20200525
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-20200525
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444

  opera:
    image: selenium/node-opera:3.141.59-20200525
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
```

Answer (score 3):

There are possible ways

1. `docker system prune` will clean up the cache and remove the dangling intermediate container and delete containers name that not actively running. This command have to be used carefully
2. `docker container prune` will delete only dead/stop containers and will free up names
3. `docker rm -v $(docker ps -aq -f 'status=exited')`
4. `docker rmi $(docker images -aq -f 'dangling=true')`
5. `docker-compose rm --force` emoves one-off containers created by docker-compose up or docker-compose run

Answer (score -1):

Just use `docker-compose up` command to start the already created containers.